# How to use predefined command in LNCS

Tags: lncs

When I check the `llncs.cls`, I find several commands that are already defined, for example:

```
\def\ackname{Acknowledgement.}  
\def\appendixname{Appendix}
```

But how to use these commands? I tried with `\begin{ackname} ... \end{ackname}`, and it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Those are macros as every other macro also, use them as `\ackname`  and `\appendixname` if needed. Though, the class probably provides other commands or environments that actually include this macros. Macros ending with `\…name` are usually set up to work with different languages (`babel`, `polyglossia`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks. I tried to use \ackname and it compiles OK, but nothing appears. Could you help me a little bit more. I'm newbie to Tex.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'm also looking for those command using \ackname correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Testing names:

\abstractname

\ackname

\appendixname

\section{Test}

\begin{abstract}
  This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\ackname}

\begin{abstract}
  This are the acknowledgements.
\end{abstract}

\section{\appendixname}
This is an appendix.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, change the line

```
\documentclass{llncs}
```

to

```
\documentclass[francais]{llncs}
```

and see what happens: all names have changed because `llncs` redefines them for French language.

[image]

---

As you can see, loading the `llncs` class with the option `francais` (you can also use the option `deutsch` to switch to German) all the names are switched to French.

Also note that this class doesn't define any predefined command for using `\appendixname` or `\ackname`. You have to load packages that use these names for exploiting them somehow.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear to me. But I thought there should be the command to generate acknowledgements and appendix.

Comment: qsp: I also expected some command for `\section{\appendixname}` (other packages provide it), especially because LNCS doesn't want it to be a section but an unnumbered run-in heading, according to `Springer_CS_Proceedings_Author_Guidelines_Jan_2013.pdf`, hence  a `\subsubsection` (though they don't write it, AFAICS).